# Memory usage when running TensorFlow operations

Tags: python, tensorflow

I noticed that TensorFlow allocates a large amount of main memory (700MB+) when running certain operations in eager mode, even on tiny tensors (i.e. with shapes as small as [5, 5]). For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf # Total memory usage is ~141MB

fst, snd = tf.random.uniform([5, 5]), tf.random.uniform([5, 5]) # ...grows to ~697MB
tf.matmul(fst, snd) # ...and then to ~1349MB
tf.concat([fst, snd], 0) # Total memory use remains ~1349MB
```

This is running on TensorFlow 2.6.0-rc1, on an RTX 3070 on Windows 10. I observed the same behaviour when enabling memory growth with `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`.

Why do the calls to `tf.matmul` and `tf.random.uniform` result in almost 700MB being allocated each time, whilst the subsequent `tf.concat` results in no change in the memory use?

Comment: Find the details on how to [Optimize TensorFlow GPU performance with the TensorFlow Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu_performance_analysis). This document guides different optimization technique. Limiting GPU memory growth can found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately this issue relates to RAM usage rather than VRAM.